# How to get photo of the day?

Tags: mysql, rating, vote

I have two tables in MySQL database:

**photos:**

```
PID - PhotoID [PK], 
DateOf - DateTime of uploading, 
UID -UserID (owner of the photo)
```

**ratings:**

```
WhoUID - UserID who rated, 
DateOf - DateTime of rate, 
RatingValue - +1 or -1 (positive or negative), 
RatingStrength - coefficient (different for each user who vote)
PID - PhotoID, [FK]
```

Real rating value = `RatingValue * RatingStrength`

What are possibilities to get "Photo of the day"?

Rules, for example:

- photo of the day must be on site at least 24 hours (since uploaded time)
- photo of the day must have at least 10 votes
- photo of the day is the photo with maximum `Real rating value` in 24 hours since uploaded time
- new photo of the day must not be already in `photo_of_day` table

UPD1.
10 votes means - at least 10 records in table `ratings` for each photo

UPD2. Is it possible to get 'photo of the day' for exact datetime? For example, how can I get photo of the day for '2011-03-11', or '2011-01-25' ?

Answer (score 0):

```
select p.PID from photos p, ratings r where
r.PID = p.PID and                             ; Link ratings to photo
p.DateOf >= '$day' and p.DateOf <= '$day' and ; Get the photos uploaded on the specified date
datediff(p.DateOf, now()) > 1 and             ; photo of the day must be on site at least 24 hours
count(r.*) >= 10 and                          ; photo should have at least 10 ratings
not exists(select p.PID from photo_of_day)    ; photo should not appear in photo_of_day
group by p.PID                                ; group the results by PID
order by sum(r.RatingValue*r.RatingStrength) desc ; order descending by RealRating
limit 1                                       ; limit the results to only one
```

This query probably takes a while, so it makes sense to not do this on every page request. You store the result in `photo_of_day` once by a script that runs once at midnight.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this. I'm not sure about 'new photo of the day must not be already in photo_of_day table', but try this one -

```
SET @exact_datetime = NOW();

SELECT p.*, SUM(r.RatingValue * r.RatingStrength) AS real_rating FROM photos p
  JOIN ratings r
    ON p.PhotoID = r.PhotoID
WHERE
  p.DateOf <= @exact_datetime - INTERVAL 1 DAY
GROUP BY
  p.PhotoID
HAVING
  count(*) >= 10
ORDER BY
  real_rating DESC
LIMIT 1
```